# Sign VBA Macro with SHA256 in Office 2010 on Windows 7

Tags: vba, certificate, ms-office, code-signing, sign

i need to sign a macro in word 2010. But only certs with sha1 are listed in the cert selection dialog.

The https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2598139 Hotfix says that "No affected products are installed".

Our AD CA is in SHA 256 mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me.

Install Office SP2 or use don't use x64 hotfix on x86 software. ;-)